# How to convert GTK UI files in some other format that can work with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gtk, gtk3

I have a GTK application which has few GTK UI files

Example -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface domain="pillar">
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="new">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes" context="stylecontextmenu|new">Cars</property>
        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="edit">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes" context="stylecontextmenu|edit">Bike</property>
        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Now I want to switch to Qt. How can I convert above files into Qt UI file that can be compatible with [QUIloader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/quiloader.html) to work with ? Is it possible

I am thinking I need to a create a kindof parser and do modifications, but not sure how to start.Thanks

Comment: Qt has a published XML Schema of their [UI format](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-ui-file-format.html), and I suppose that a similar one exists for GTK too. Unfortunately, "porting" one to the other requires proper knowledge of **both** frameworks, also considering that some aspects may not be done in the same way. While a similar tool may be interesting, your purpose is to switch to Qt, not create a tool to do that: frankly, it would be quite simpler and much faster to just redo the UI from scratch in Qt Designer.